# IPN Simulator "Cannot extract response: no Content-Type found"

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Since PayPal rolled out some changes to their developer APIs over the last couple of weeks, I've noticed that the IPN simulator on the developer centre is no longer responding to test IPN's as I would expect.  Now, it's spitting out the message:

*"IPN Delivery Failed:Cannot extract response: no Content-Type found"*

The test IPN itself *seems* to actually be executing just fine - my IPN controller (in ASP) is receiving the IPN, echoing it back, and PayPal is responding with "VERIFIED" as I would expect.

Is this just a simulator frontend bug, or am I missing something here?  My code is (as far as I can tell) definitely sending the ContentType header, just as it always has been:

```
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; <-- ## HEADER IS PRESENT ##
byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Request.ContentLength);
string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;
```

It's worth noting that I'm using nginx as a proxy to forward the IPN requests to my local development server, since Microsoft's development test server is (very stupidly) only accessible locally. I don't know if this could affect the outcome, but it *did* work fine just a week or so ago before PayPal's changes.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - this looks like your IPN handler itself is not returning a proper HTTP 200 response after receiving the IPN message from PayPal. Here is the sequence:

1. PayPal sends IPN message
2. Your IPN handler receives the IPN message and return HTTP 200 (w/ no data in response)
3. Your IPN handler send a POST message to PayPal to verify.

Looks like #2 is where it's failing. I would recommend checking your IPN script to make sure it's returning successful response as soon as it receives the IPN message (even before sending the IPN for verification).

Comment: Perfect - thanks so much. It's odd that the same code always used to produce the Green tick and "IPN Sent Successfully" using the old simulator.  Anyway, I shoved the following code before I send the IPN back:

    Response.Clear();
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    Response.Write("");
    Response.End();

This seemed to do the trick. Guess I didn't read the manual properly, after all.

Comment: @Praveen - can you reference a link to the documentation that specifies this flow?  It seems to me that this is a bad API design - how do you guarantee that the HTTP 200 response arrives at PayPal before the IPN Handler POST?

Comment: the documentation is here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

hmm not sure I completely understand you comment on the bad API design but every HTTP request must have a response - correct ? So when you receive an IPN message as a HTTP request from PayPal, you MUST respond with a response code 200 saying "yes I received it". If that doesn't happen, PayPal thinks that your server has never received the IPN message and it would try to send it again.

Comment: also there is no requirement that the response code 200 (in step 2 above) must be returned before making the verify call in step 3. But if the step 3 is taking too long, the request in step 2 might time out - making PayPal think that the IPN message has never made it to your server. Hence the recommendation to return 200 response code as soon as you receive it and then take care of the verification step. You can do that as a separate asynchronous thread to verify the IPN message. HTH.

Comment: The 'Response.Write("");' part is very important. The simulator will return the "no Content-Type found" error if you only set the 200 code and no content. See my post here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105718/paypal-sandbox-ipn-not-detecting-content-type